# Strapi - Delete an item from nested repeatable component

Tags: graphql, strapi

I would like to know if it is possible to delete an item from a nested object via API or graphQL. I have a collection type (restaurant) with a repeatable component inside called "franchise" (Florida and New York). I would like to delete just one of those (Florida for example). Is that possible?

API GET

```json
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Italian Food",
            "address": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:50.831Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:51.632Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:51.629Z",
            "franchise": [{
                "id": 4,
                "state": "Florida"
            }, {
                "id": 5,
                "state": "New York"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "meta": {
        "pagination": {
            "page": 1,
            "pageSize": 25,
            "pageCount": 1,
            "total": 1
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Strapi works.  There is no direct way to delete components. It is not impossible but...

In your case I would consider and refactor franchises to be a collection type rather than a repeatable component.

Here is a great talk around content modeling in Strapi https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDnWCnA6qTg

But if you wanted to delete the component, you would have to do a update `mutation` on `restaurant` collection type.

And pass in the whole object, minus the franchise you want to remove.

```
"data": [{
        "id": 2,
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Italian Food",
            "address": null,
            "createdAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:50.831Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:51.632Z",
            "publishedAt": "2023-09-16T19:13:51.629Z",
            "franchise": [{
                "id": 5,
                "state": "New York"
            }]
        }
    }],
```

This will update `restaurant` collection type and remove Florida franchise.

Since we are not passing it in the update mutation, Strapi will delete it.

But the best approach would be to convert it to a `collection` type vs a `component`.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hey Paul, I will think on both options. Thank for clarifying that. The talk in the video is very good as well. 